How do I simulate gravity in a C++ SFML Solar System Simulation?
I'm trying to write a Solar System Simulation in C++ using SFML. So far I got the planets on the screen along with the sun, and I wrote the code to get the planets to orbit around the sun:
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp";

#include <cmath>;
#include <ctime>;
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;

const double G = 6.67430e-11; // Gravitational constant

class CelestialBody {
public:
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Vector2f velocity;
    float mass;

    CelestialBody(float radius, float mass, sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2f velocity, sf::Color color)
        : mass(mass), position(position), velocity(velocity) {
        shape.setRadius(radius);
        shape.setOrigin(radius, radius);
        shape.setPosition(position);
        shape.setFillColor(color);
    }

    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> path;

    // Update this in your CelestialBody::update method
    void update(float dt) {
        position += velocity * dt;
        shape.setPosition(position);
        path.push_back(position); // Store the new position
    }
};

void applyGravity(CelestialBody& a, CelestialBody& b, float dt) {
    sf::Vector2f direction = b.position - a.position;
    float distance = sqrt(direction.x * direction.x + direction.y * direction.y);
    if (distance == 0) return; // Avoid division by zero
    float force = (G * a.mass * b.mass) / (distance * distance);
    sf::Vector2f normalizedDirection = direction / distance;
    sf::Vector2f accelerationA = force / a.mass * normalizedDirection;
    a.velocity += accelerationA * dt;
}


sf::VertexArray createStarField(int numStars, int width, int height) {
    sf::VertexArray stars(sf::Points, numStars);
    for (int i = 0; i < numStars; ++i) {
        stars[i].position = sf::Vector2f(rand() % width - width / 2, rand() % height - height / 2);
        stars[i].color = sf::Color::White;
    }
    return stars;
}

int main() {
    const int window_width = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    const int window_height = sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(window_width, window_height), "C++ Solar System");

    // Create a view
    sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, window_width, window_height));

    // Scaling factors
    float radiusScale = 1.0f / 1000000.0f;
    float distanceScale = 1.0f / 1000000.0f;
    float massScale = 1e11 / 1e24;

    // Create solar system
    CelestialBody sun(45.0f, 1.989e30 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2), sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Color(239, 142, 56));

    // MERCURY
    float mercuryDistance = 57.9e6 * distanceScale;
    float mercuryVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / mercuryDistance);
    CelestialBody mercury(2.440, 3.30e23 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - mercuryDistance), sf::Vector2f(mercuryVelocity, 0), sf::Color(183, 184, 185));

    // VENUS
    float venusDistance = 108.2e6 * distanceScale;
    float venusVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / venusDistance);
    CelestialBody venus(6.052, 4.87e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - venusDistance), sf::Vector2f(venusVelocity, 0), sf::Color(255, 198, 73));

    // EARTH
    float earthDistance = 149.6e6 * distanceScale;
    float earthVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / earthDistance);
    CelestialBody earth(6.371, 5.972e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - earthDistance), sf::Vector2f(earthVelocity, 0), sf::Color(26, 40, 90));

    // MARS
    float marsDistance = 227.9e6 * distanceScale;
    float marsVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / marsDistance);
    CelestialBody mars(3.390, 0.642e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - marsDistance), sf::Vector2f(marsVelocity, 0), sf::Color(156, 46, 53));

    // JUPITER
    float jupiterDistance = 778.5e6 * distanceScale;
    float jupiterVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / jupiterDistance);
    CelestialBody jupiter(69.911, 1898e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - jupiterDistance), sf::Vector2f(jupiterVelocity, 0), sf::Color(106, 81, 119));

    // SATURN
    float saturnDistance = 1433.5e6 * distanceScale;
    float saturnVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / saturnDistance);
    CelestialBody saturn(58.232, 568e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - saturnDistance), sf::Vector2f(saturnVelocity, 0), sf::Color(250, 229, 191));
    
    // URANUS
    float uranusDistance = 2872.5e6 * distanceScale;
    float uranusVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / uranusDistance);
    CelestialBody uranus(25.362, 86.8e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - uranusDistance), sf::Vector2f(uranusVelocity, 0), sf::Color(178, 214, 219));

    // Neptune
    float neptuneDistance = 4495.1e6 * distanceScale;
    float neptuneVelocity = sqrt(G * (1.989e30 * massScale) / neptuneDistance);
    CelestialBody neptune(24.622, 102e24 * massScale, sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2 - neptuneDistance), sf::Vector2f(neptuneVelocity, 0), sf::Color(41, 144, 181));
    
    // Draw Star Field
    sf::VertexArray stars = createStarField(1000000, window_width * 10, window_height * 10);

    sf::Clock clock;
    float timeScale = 0.3141592650f;

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            // Handle zoom in and zoom out
            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseWheelScrolled) {
                if (event.mouseWheelScroll.delta > 0) {
                    view.zoom(0.9f); // Zoom in
                }
                else {
                    view.zoom(1.1f); // Zoom out
                }
            }
        }

        float dt = clock.restart().asSeconds() * timeScale;

        // Apply gravity
        applyGravity(mercury, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(venus, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(earth, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(mars, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(jupiter, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(saturn, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(uranus, sun, dt);
        applyGravity(neptune, sun, dt);

        // Update positions
        sun.update(dt);
        mercury.update(dt);
        venus.update(dt);
        earth.update(dt);
        mars.update(dt);
        jupiter.update(dt);
        saturn.update(dt);
        uranus.update(dt);
        neptune.update(dt);

        // Apply the view
        window.setView(view);

        window.clear();
         
        for (auto& planet : { mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune }) {
            sf::VertexArray pathLine(sf::LinesStrip, planet.path.size());
            for (size_t i = 0; i < planet.path.size(); ++i) {
                pathLine[i].position = planet.path[i];
            }
            window.draw(pathLine);
        }

        window.draw(sun.shape);
        window.draw(mercury.shape);
        window.draw(venus.shape);
        window.draw(earth.shape);
        window.draw(mars.shape);
        window.draw(jupiter.shape);
        window.draw(saturn.shape);
        window.draw(uranus.shape);
        window.draw(neptune.shape);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

However, the planets gradually move further away or closer to the sun. I have no idea what's wrong.
Could someone help me fix this bug?
Here is an image of what happens to one of the planets (Mercury) after a while:

As you can see the path that Mercury makes becomes thicker as it gets further or closer away from the sun over time.

In general, you will have problems with this due to the integration you are doing. Euler Integration will always diverge, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method. Also, you're dealing with pretty big numbers, even after your scaling. It could be that you're running into numerical precision issues.

If your orbit has the right diameter then you are almost certainly applying gravity correctly. I agree with Bert: you are using forward Euler, which is only first-order accurate. I suggest using Runge-Kutta. There is a slight inconsistency in your equations - namely, ignoring Newton’s third law. However, it’s not the cause of your problem.

There is a subtle mistake that you can make in the implementation of the first order Euler method that makes this particular problem a bit better (it was described in one of the astronomy teaching journals ~1984). Apart from that to get reasonable long term behaviour needs something like RK4, Numerov or Adams-Bashford or even more esoteric symplectic integration (the latter by design attempts to conserve energy and momentum in phase space). But also the hardest to use or understand.

So how can I implement Runge-Kutta and Newton's third law in this code? Sorry, this is my first time in C++ and astronomy.

Boost's odeint package has rk45 which should be accurate enough (but slow), but if you want super accurate one you need a solver that conserves energy ... there are multiple approx ones that are fast enough for game engines  in publications but i don't know a package that implement any other than the available physics engines like "bullet" and  similar ones.

Boost odeint even has an example of a solar system in its tutorials https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/solar_system.html it is using a stiff solver in the example as appropriate

Thanks, Ahmed! This looks great. I'm going to try it and see if it works.

As indicated in the comments, you followed the strategy of the Euler method. But in the usual way of an implmentation "close to the physics" that did not result in the Euler method for systems, but in the semi-implicit or symplectic Euler method. This has the advantage that instead of outward spirals you almost get closed periodic orbits.
It is well-known that the symplectic Euler method, started with values for a circular motion, will distort the orbit to a slgiht ellipse and that this ellipse will rotate around the origin. With the right step size and done long enough this gives nice dot patterns.
You could correct the method towards leapfrog Verlet of second order by "correcting" the initial conditions by a half-step backwards in only the velocities.
Note that the symplectic methods to be symplectic require that the step size is really fixed, no variable step size, no adapting to the frame intervals. That does not make a really visible difference, so one can also ignore this.
